# Where to put flot plugins within Laravel 4 structure

Tags: php, laravel, flot

Hi all i have been using flot in my Laravel project and have been using the links to the content delivery network to access flots libraries. But as im upgrading my code i have found that these links lack certain aspects that i need for example x axis labels. I have now downloaded the flot source files but do not know where to put them in regards to my Laravel project structure. any tips or advice would be grand..

Thanks in advance

EDIT

for example i have placed the source files within my project under the vendor tab and linked it like so

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"src="vendor/js/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real answer to your question. You place them where you want them to be. `public/vendor/js/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js` is perfectly fine. As long as you have a way to display them to the browser.

I place my assets in `app/assets/x` and use [`Basset`](https://github.com/Marwelln/basset) to manage (show, minify etc.) them.

Comment: Thanks for your response! i kind of have what i need now prob just a bit more tweeking